# Is it possible to define the type for "template function pointer"?

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to define the type for "template function pointer"? Such as

```
void (*tfp<99>)(); // can't compile
```

just as the template class can do:

```
Someclass<99>();
```

To explain my problem further, I have the following code:

```
template <int N>
class Foo {};

template <int N>
void foo() {}

template <int N, template <int> class OP>
void test_foo(OP<N> op) { std::cout << N << std::endl; }
```

I can call `test_foo(Foo<99>())`, but can't call `test_foo()` with the argument `foo<99>`:

```
test_foo(Foo<99>());                    //OK
test_foo(foo<99>);                      //error: candidate template ignored: could not match '<N>' against 'void (*)()'
test_foo<void (*)()>(foo<99>);          //error: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'N'
test_foo<void (*<99>)()>(foo<99>);      //error: expected expression
test_foo<void (*<99>)()<99> >(foo<99>); //error: expected expression
```

Is there an approach can get the template parameter `N` in `test_foo()` from the argument `foo<99>` just like `test_foo(Foo<99>())` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can in C++11 with template aliases:

```
template <int V> using fptr = void (*tfp<V>)();
```

You cannot do "traits" on those fptr values (or deduce the template arguments from a `&foo<N>` function parameter), because the value of a function template instantiation does ***not*** encode the template arguments into the resultant type.

This is different for class templates.